# Downcasting object without copying in EF

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, entity-framework-6

I have a database that will essentialy log all activity in our project down to very specific events - as such, a bunch of records will be created daily. As I'd like to minimize the DB size, I got rid of the Discrimintator column by marking all entry child classes with the NotMapped annotation. For example:

I have two classes:

```
public class Base {
    public virtual void Validate(){return; };
}

[NotMapped]
public class Derived:Base {
    public override void Validate(){DoSomethingWithData(); return; };
}
```

This all works fine, I have no Discriminator column, but here's the catch. I have a different Validate() method for every derived class (the classes and data are quite complex). When I parse data, I create a Child class, fill in lists of data, run the Validate() function, and if it return true, I'd like to add a **Base** object to the database. Now EF won't let me, as it still detects the object as Child (which it really is underneath, but still). I get an exception, telling me no mapping data for the Child class was found and the insert has failed. Is there a way around this without deep copying the Child into a new Base object?

Comment: This sounds like a good candidate for a revision of your Entity model, but without knowing more about how you've defined your entities I'm not sure (hence commenting rather than answering!)

Is your Base class an Event entity that needs to be saved? How are you intending to retrieve your Derived entity from the database if you're only storing the data needed for your Base class, or are you storing all of the data for your Derived entities in other tables?

Comment: Hello @GrahamHarper, let me explain a bit more. The base class contains a bit of common metadata, like when, who and what, the latter being dumbed down by enums to an integer value. Everything else about the events is stored in a list of metadata objects, which are essentially key-value pairs. The reason for this lies in later use of this data for analysis, I'll leave it at that. The only thing the Child contains is the Validate() function override to check if the proper metadata for the event type exists in the list before insertion. Basically, I use classes instead of a giant switch.